# Convert application/postscript to JPG

Tags: google-apps-script, file-conversion

I'm hoping to convert an EPS file to a JPG or a PDF using Google Apps Script, and I'm wondering if it's possible. I started with this code:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
var conversion = file.makeCopy().getAs('image/jpeg');
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error message:

"Converting from application/postscript to image/jpeg is not supported."

Is it possible to make this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert EPS file (`application/postscript`) to the Jpeg format (`image/jpeg`) using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `getAs` cannot directly convert from `application/postscript` to `image/jpeg`. I think that this is the current specification. So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose this workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve file metadata using the method of "Files: get" in Drive API.
2. Retrieve the EPS file (`application/postscript`) as PNG format, and convert it to Jpeg format.
3. Create the Jpeg data as a file.

When above flow is used as a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

When you use this, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. In this sample script, the EPS file is converted to Jpeg format.

```
var fileID = "###";  // Please set the file ID of the EPS file.

// 1. Retrieve file metadata using Drive API.
var res = Drive.Files.get(fileID);

// 2. Retrieve the EPS file (`application/postscript`) as PNG format, and convert it to Jpeg format.
var blob = UrlFetchApp
  .fetch(res.thumbnailLink.replace("s220", "s1000"))
  .getBlob()
  .getAs(MimeType.JPEG)
  .setName(res.title.split(".")[0] + ".jpg");

// 3. Create the Jpeg data as a file.
DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

#### Note:

- In above workaround, the EPS format is converted to the PNG format using Drive API, and the PNG format is converted to the Jpeg format using `getAs`. But in this workaround, it cannot convert to the PDF format. So if you want to convert the EPS format to the PDF format, I think that the external API like https://www.convertapi.com/eps-to-pdf might be suitable.

#### References:

- [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#getAs(String))
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get)

Comment: Great answer ! Always detailed !

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#getAs(String)), you should be able to use `getAs('application/pdf')`

> For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images
> in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif',
> 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message when I use that command unfortunately. That was the first way I tried, but no luck.

Comment: You may have to locate a 3rd party conversion API if you need to dynamically create the files, in that case.